# How to search for a word in a file, put it in an array then delete it in C

Tags: c, fopen, scanf

I just started learning C. My first project is a program that reads text from a text file and then formats it based on the commands in the file.

My way of solving this was to make the program scan through the text file, locate the commands, remove them from the text file and then put them in array. Then run the rest of the text through if statements of each command.

For example if the command is remove excess whitespace, it removes excess whitespace from the code and so on. So far I just have a code that reads the file and prints it out

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 FILE *fp;
 char *filename;
 char ch;



// Check if a filename has been specified in the command
  if (argc < 2)
   {
        printf("Missing Filename\n");
        return(1);
   }
   else
  {
        filename = argv[1];
        printf("Filename : %s\n", filename);
   }

   // Open file in read-only mode
   fp = fopen(filename,"r");


   // If file opened successfully, then print the contents
   if ( fp )
      {
        printf("File contents:\n");
        while ( (ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF )
           {
                printf("%c",ch);
           }

       }
   else
      {
         printf("Failed to open the file\n");
        }

return(0);
}
```

This code isn't completely mine I should point out.

My problem is. I'm trying to write a piece of code that scans through the text file, finds a particular word, removes it from the text file and saves it in an array. That's it. Once the word has been found in the text file, it is saved in an array and then deleted from the text file. This word will be a formatting option. And the text is then formatted according to what the option is and then printed out into another text file.

For example, it scans a text and finds the word "LW30" this word means each line should only have 30 characters at most. Once the program finds this option it formats the text according to what the option means. It could be more than one option each meaning different things but there are only 5 options possible and of course, it will be reading a random text file so I don't know what the options will be.

The formatting commands are:

.LW(width) each line is formatted so that there is never more than 'width' characters in each line

.LM(left) here each line following the the command will be indented 'left' spaces from the left hand margin. The indent is included in the page width.

.FT[off|on] this is used to turn formatting on and off. If the command appears with "off", then all text below the command up to the next ".FT"command is output without being formatted. If it appears with "on", then all text below the command up to the next ".FT" command is output with as many words as will fill the given page width

.LS(linespacing) if "linespacing"is not zero (0) then between each text line there will appear linespacing blank lines. A blank line in the input file is considered to be the same as a text line.

Also, each command will have it's own line in the text

I'd really appreciate some help with this.

Comment: Please be specific about what problems are in the code that you need help with. Have you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: It's not a good idea to modify the file and read it again. Instead, you should analyse it on the fly. However, the answer depends on the structure of the file you take as input. Without further information, we cannot really help

Comment: @Gerhard I've edited it, I restated my problem in a paragraph after the code. Please tell me if I need to be more clear

Comment: @ThomasWilmotte It reads from a text file, what do you mean analyse it on the fly? Sorry, I just started learning C and I can't really apply my java or c# knowledge here.

Comment: @DrewU Sorry, I misunderstood you problem at the first read, I didn't understand that modifying the file was a part of the problem

Comment: @DrewU Just one question. If you're looking for a particular word in the file to save this word in an array ... why do you read the file? I mean you already know the word ... or do you want to count the number of words and to remove them from the file? What's the point of storing the word in an array actually?

Comment: @ThomasWilmotte Well, the text file will have a certain words which stand for formatting options. I have to go through this file, find the formatting options and then format the file according to those options

Comment: maybe you could supply a small example of the file?

Comment: @DrewU Ok, so you don't need just to remove the word, you need to perform additional operation on the file, which may change the way of handling the problem. As Anders suggested, could you provide an example of the file to parse or a list of the formatting options/rules?

Comment: @ThomasWilmotte sure

Comment: @ThomasWilmotte just did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the kind of problem that has to be divided into small ones in order to be easily solved.

1. Read the input file line per lines

   a. if it's a formatting command, change the state of the program with the formatting options

   b. else print the line correctly formatted to a temporary file
2. Override the input file with the content of the temporary file.

First, let's define a few types that will be reused later. If you're new to C, I invite you to check [this page](https://www-s.acm.illinois.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/1.2.html#struct) and read what are `enum`, `struct` and `union`.

An enumeration of the possible commands

```
typedef enum Command_e { CMD_NONE, LW , LM , FT , LS } Command;
```

An enumaration of the different kind of lines. Basically you have two kind of lines: the regular lines to be formatted and the one containing the commands

```
typedef enum LineType_e { LT_NONE, REGULAR , COMMAND } LineType;
```

A structure representing a line. A line contains its type. Additionally, a `REGULAR` line contains its length and its content. A `COMMAND` contains its type and its parameter. We will represent the `on` and `off` values respectively by `1` and `0`.

```
typedef struct Line_s
{
  LineType type;

  union
  {
    struct cmd_s
    {
      Command type;
      int     arg;
    } cmd;

    struct reg_s
    {
      char * str;
      size_t len;
    } reg;

  } content;

} Line;
```

In C, there is no standard `getline` function. However, it's easy to do one with the `fgets` function.

```
// Read a line from the stream and returns a string containing every
// characters of the line until a newline character is read or end-of-file
// is reached. size is filled with the size of the string including the
// newline character.
// If end-of-file is reached before any character is read, the function
// returns NULL
char * getline(FILE * stream, size_t * s)
{
  char * buf   = NULL; // Buffer to return
  int    cnt   = 0;
  int    size  = 0;    // Buffer size
  int    start = 0;    // Where to start writing in the buffer

  do
  {
    // Resize the buffer to (2^cnt * BUFF_SIZE) and fill the expanded
    // part with the a null character
    size  = BUFF_SIZE * (1 << cnt);
    start = BUFF_SIZE * (1 << (cnt - 1)) - 1;
    start = start < 0 ? 0 : start;
    buf   = realloc(buf, size * sizeof(char));

    memset(& buf[start], '\0', size - start);

    // Read a maximum of (size - start) characters from the stream or
    // until a newline character has been reached
    fgets(& buf[start], size - start, stream);
    cnt ++;
  } // Loop until a complete line has been read
  while(buf[size - 2] != '\0' &&
        buf[size - 2] != '\n' &&
        ! feof(stdin));

  // If nothing has been read from the file, free the memory and returns
  // a NULL pointer
  if(buf[0] == '\0')
  {
    free(buf);
    buf   = NULL;
    (* s) = 0;
  }
  else
  {
    (* s) = strlen(buf);
  }

  return buf;
}
```

Where `BUFF_SIZE` is a macro that defines the typical size for a buffer. This function requires to include `string.h` because it's using `memset` and `stdlib.h` in order to use `realloc`.

Given this function, you can easily write another one that will read the file line per line and that will fill a `Line` structure passed as input and return an integer equal to zero if end-of-file has been reached.

```
int getNextLine(FILE * stream, Line * line)
{
  size_t   size;
  char   * str = getline(stream, & size);

  if(! str)
  {
    line->type = LT_NONE;
    return 0;
  }

  str[size - 1] = '\0'; // Remove the newline character

  if(size - 1 > 2)
  {
    if(str[0] == 'L' && (str[1] == 'W' || str[1] == 'M' || str[1] == 'S'))
    {
      // If the remaining of the string is made characters between '0' and
      // '9', then, str is a LW, LM or LS command
      int val = 0;
      int i;
      for(i = 2; i < size - 1; i ++)
      {
        if(str[i] < '0' || str[i] > '9') break;

        val = val * 10 + (str[i] - '0');
      }

      if(i < size - 1)
      {
        line->type            = REGULAR;
        line->content.reg.str = str;
        line->content.reg.len = size;
      }
      else
      {
        line->type            = COMMAND;
        line->content.cmd.arg = val;

        switch(str[1])
        {
          case 'W' : line->content.cmd.type = LW; break;
          case 'M' : line->content.cmd.type = LM; break;
          case 'S' : line->content.cmd.type = LS; break;
        }
      }

      return 1;
    }

    if(size - 1 == 4 && str[0] == 'F' && str[1] == 'T' &&
                        str[2] == 'o' && str[3] == 'n')
    {
      // FTon command found
      line->type             = COMMAND;
      line->content.cmd.type = FT;
      line->content.cmd.arg  = 1;

      return 1;
    }

    if(size - 1 == 5 && str[0] == 'F' && str[1] == 'T' &&
                        str[2] == 'o' && str[3] == 'f' && str[4] == 'f')
    {
      // FToff command found
      line->type     = COMMAND;
      line->content.cmd.type = FT;
      line->content.cmd.arg  = 0;

      return 1;
    }
  }

  // If we reach this point no command have been found
  line->type    = REGULAR;
  line->content.reg.str = str;
  line->content.reg.len = size;

  return 1;
}
```

Now, you're almost done. In a main loop which will stop when `getNextLine` will return `0`, you can set a few variables according to the commands you received and when you receive a regular line, you can just call a format function that will output the line formatted as it should in a stream. Here is an example of such a function.

```
void format(FILE * stream, Line line, int ft, int lw, int lm, int ls)
{
  if(! ft)
  {
    // If the formatting is disabled, simply send the line to the stream
    fprintf(stream, "%s\n", line.content.reg.str);
  }
  else
  {
    int  i;
    int  j;
    char f[16] = { 0 };
    sprintf(f, "%%.%ds\n", lw - lm);

    i = 0;

    do
    {
      for(j = 0; j < lm; j ++) fprintf(stream, " ");
      fprintf(stream, f, & line.content.reg.str[i * (lw - lm)]);
      for(j = 0; j < ls; j ++) fprintf(stream, "\n");

      i++;
    }
    while(i * (lw - lm) < line.content.reg.len);
  }
}
```

The temporary file I talked about before can be open with the [`tmpfile`](https://www-s.acm.illinois.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.12.html#tmpfile) function. When you reach the end of the input file, you just have to close your input file and copy the content of the temporary file into it. This is simply done with `buffers` and `fprintf`. Don't forget to free the memory calling the `free` function after you printed the formatted line into the temporary file in order to avoid memory leaks.

At the end, a file like

```
FTon
LW30
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam est arcu, congue vehicula consectetur in, tempus ac ex. Integer urna lectus, maximus vel felis sed, dapibus gravida risus. Curabitur diam arcu, accumsan at magna id, laoreet condimentum ante.

FToff
Nulla id velit justo. Aenean leo risus, interdum lobortis enim sit amet, aliquet elementum dolor. Morbi pretium velit sed mauris molestie viverra. Cras ut cursus nibh. Aliquam ut aliquam nunc, eget rhoncus sapien.

LS1
Sed efficitur justo aliquam orci molestie, vel condimentum dui semper. Sed lobortis dignissim ligula ut bibendum. Pellentesque finibus euismod massa a congue.

FTon
Sed placerat quam eget ante rutrum pretium a in orci. Quisque id lorem dapibus, tincidunt lorem et, convallis orci. Etiam sed placerat ante.

LM5
Donec mi est, sodales sed faucibus ac, elementum eu velit. Nam mollis varius porttitor. Sed dignissim sodales malesuada.
LW15
Donec nec tempus turpis, at condimentum velit.
```

Will give you the following output

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, co
nsectetur adipiscing elit. Ali
quam est arcu, congue vehicula
 consectetur in, tempus ac ex.
 Integer urna lectus, maximus
vel felis sed, dapibus gravida
 risus. Curabitur diam arcu, a
ccumsan at magna id, laoreet c
ondimentum ante.

Nulla id velit justo. Aenean leo risus, interdum lobortis enim sit amet, aliquet elementum dolor. Morbi pretium velit sed mauris molestie viverra. Cras ut cursus nibh. Aliquam ut aliquam nunc, eget rhoncus sapien.

Sed efficitur justo aliquam orci molestie, vel condimentum dui semper. Sed lobortis dignissim ligula ut bibendum. Pellentesque finibus euismod massa a congue.

Sed placerat quam eget ante ru

trum pretium a in orci. Quisqu

e id lorem dapibus, tincidunt

lorem et, convallis orci. Etia

m sed placerat ante.



     Donec mi est, sodales sed

      faucibus ac, elementum e

     u velit. Nam mollis variu

     s porttitor. Sed dignissi

     m sodales malesuada.

     Donec nec

     tempus tur

     pis, at co

     ndimentum

     velit.
```

Comment: I appreciate you explaining each part. There are still certain parts I don't get but I'll just look into them. I don't plan on like copying your work exactly, I still want to do myself so I learn but I'll use this to help. Maybe just copy little blocks of the code but thank you. This was really well done

Comment: That's the spirit! Feel free to comment here if you need more info